# Convert Gregorian date to Julian date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, julian-date

I have a df like so:

```
ImageDate   Year   Month   Day
20020506    2002   05      06
20030605    2003   06      05
20040201    2002   02      01
```

and I want to add a new column which converts the dates into julian dates.  I am pretty sure I need the module `datetime` to do this, but I looked through the docs and didn't find anything that was apparent to me on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Go take a look at this library : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jdcal

And do something like : `

> > > from jdcal import gcal2jd, jd2gcal
> > >
> > > gcal2jd(2000,1,1)'

Answer (score 2):

## First Solution

The following is my python implementation of the original conversion algorithm published [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=364097):

```
def gregorian_to_julian(year, month, day):
    i = int((month - 14) / 12)
    jd = day - 32075
    jd += int((1461 * (year + 4800 + i)) / 4)
    jd += int((367 * (month - 2 - (12 * i))) / 12)
    jd -= int((3 * int((year + 4900 + i) / 100)) / 4)
    return jd
```

For example:

```
>>> gregorian_to_julian(1970, 1, 1)
2440588
```

---

## Second Solution

alternatively, you can use the built-in date object to get the Julian date from Gregorian date by adding the Julian date of Gregorian absolute date 0 which is 1,721,425 to ordinal date as published [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/papers/CalendricalCalculationsII.pdf):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date(1970, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1721425
2440588
```

---

The second solution is simpler and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Import python datetime library.
import datetime as dt
#Lets consider you want to convert the below date. You can have the  date in any order like CCYY-MM-YY or MM-DD-CCYY or with different separator like CCYY/MM/YY.
GregDate = '2020-03-30'
# Specify the date and format within strptime in this case format is %Y-%m-%d (if your data was 2020/03/30' then use %Y/%m/%d) and specify the format you want to convert into in strftime, in this case it is %Y%j. This gives out Julian date in the form CCYYDDD, if you need only in YYDDD give the format as %y%j
Juldate = dt.datetime.strptime(GregDate, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y%j')
# Print your variable to display the result
print(Juldate)
```

```
2020090
```

Comment: you can control the format using %Y-%m-%d and if you need only year part in the Julian date like 20090 use ('%y%j')

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25743418)

Comment: Done, Thank you.. will take care in future.